# Tooltip on user's question list should show accurate number of views and not fixed value "thousands"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, profile-page, views

Tooltip for view count on user's page does not display accurate view count, it seems to just display "thousands" if the viewcount > 1000. Everywhere else the tooltip displays the accurate value, and I was expecting the accurate view count here.

See for example https://stackoverflow.com/users/1431/juha-syrjala

http://img528.imageshack.us/img528/3867/stackoverflowtooltip.png

The actual view count for that question is 4,196 at the time I am writing this.

The html fragment in question is this:

```
<div class="views"> 
    <div class="mini-counts warm"><span title='thousand'>4</span></div> 
    <div class='warm'>kviews</div> 
</div>
```

It should be like something like this:

```
<div class="views"> 
    <div class="mini-counts warm" title="4,196 views">4</div> 
    <div class='warm' title="4,196 views">kviews</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: It's fair to note that there is *no* tooltip if there is less than 1000 views.

Comment: The same is true on the home page. No tooltip if < 1000, "thousand" if  >= 1000

Comment: Wow, you guys are great. Always open to feature requests. Good show!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree here. All this is saying is 'Hey dummy, kviews means thousand views'.

Since there is already a rule that the tooltip is only shown for >1000 (which I agree with since it is the only time counts are fully displayed), seeing the actual count would be nice.