# Add a tooltip to view count on search result page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, tooltips, views

There is no tooltip on search result page on view count field if a question has more than 1000 views. That view count field is located just below of vote and answer count fields on the left.

See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=java&sort=votes&pagesize=50 and its first question which has following html code:

```
<div class="views hot">31k views</div>
```

In most places this kind of inaccurate values have tooltips which show the actual accurate value. Thus, the above fragment should have `title="31,157 views"` attribute.

If there is less than 1000 views, the search result page shows to accurate view count and no tooltip is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been now implemented. However, there is always a tooltip, even when it is not needed. i.e. when view count is < 1000

Comment: I see the actual view count for 1k+, but I can't reproduce the other behaviour. You may want to start a new question to deal with that issue.

Comment: @Jon Are you referring to the view counts on the profiles ( [which was a separate question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47392/) ) or the view counts on the search page (this question)? I can reproduce it myself in the latter, I tested it with the link provided in the question.

Comment: @ccornet: Oh, I see now. No-repro on the homepage and my user profile, but there is always a tooltip on the Questions page.

Comment: @Jon I am referring the search result page. The link in question shows only answers with > 1000 view count on the first page. Try for example http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+open+source . There is a tooltip "269 views".

Comment: Yes, I went to the last page to see those with < 1000 views.